# Div with Two Columns Containing Vertically Centred Divs of Different Heights

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

**Background**

I have a div with two columns. In column A, there will be a div with an "About Me" section. This is height X. In column B will be another image of a map. This is height Y. X is not equal to Y.

I am making both columns (combined) = to `100vw`. Each column is defined as `50%`.

(I can calculate the height of the map in column B with the following math (which can be seen more clearly in the linked Jfiddle): Image is `350x600px`. If `350px` = `50%`, then `600px` = ~171%. `171 / 2 = 85.5%` so the following code snippet *should* give the correct transform value:

`margin-top: 85.5%;
transform: translateY(-50%);`)

**Objective**

I would like the column height to adjust to the height of the tallest element. The tallest element will most likely *always* be in column B. I would like the div in column A to sit halfway down the page. However, if I should ever change the order and want to put something taller in column A than in column B, it would be really great to have a fallback so that the element in column B repositions itself to become vertically centred. (But I can live without that and do it manually should I need to.)

**Problem**

- Column heights aren't behaving themselves. The height of column A (shown in dark green) is higher than that of column B, even though the element in A is shorter.

**Jfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/ubjo1s3y/28/

(With nice bright div colours)

**Code**

css:

```
.column {
    margin: -5px 0px 30px 0px;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  height: auto;
    background-color: green;
}

.row:after {
    background-color: pink;
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}

#aboutmecontainer {
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 90%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 5% 0px 5%;
    margin-top: 85.5%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#facephoto {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 130px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#aboutmetext {
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#map {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    float: left;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 0px 5% 0px 5%;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <!-- container for round face photo -->
        <div id="aboutmecontainer">
            <div id="facephoto">
                <!-- photo -->
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="Face" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain;" />
            </div>
            <!-- container for text underneath face photo -->
            <div id="aboutmetext"><h3 style="color: #000000;">About Me</h3><p></p><h5 style="color: #000000;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <!-- div for map to right of "about me" section -->
        <div id="map">
            <!-- map picture can be edited in photoshop to add new countries -->
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x600" alt="Map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: contain;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding this JFiddle to show the correct solution as given by @jmulder5 - the vertical translation of the element inside the div was warping the height of the column container. http://jsfiddle.net/ubjo1s3y/32/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would definitely recommend learning how to use flexbox.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox.

Additionally, using floats in this situation is going to ruin the flow of the dom. There are situations where using floats can work, but it removes the targeted element from the regular flow of the dom and will always cause you grief if you don't know how to use floats.
Here is a revised jsfiddle that does not use flex. You want to set `.column`'s display to `inline-block` and put `font-size: 0` on `.row` (removing white-space). And remove all of your floats.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubjo1s3y/33/)

Comment: Roger that @jmulder5 - thanks for the response and I will be looking into flex boxes soon. However, looking at your revised JFiddle, I can't see that my problem in the question has been solved... I still see that that column (dark green background colour) is taller than the element in column B... That is what I'm really trying to get to the bottom of right now :)

Comment: I can't yet comment on other posts due to lack of reputation. First time on here. The `margin-top` and `translateY` are stretching your left column

Comment: you hit the nail on the head! Very grateful; thank you! I'm going to mark your answer as correct  - when you have the reputation to do so, please edit your answer to include your comment above. All the best!

Comment: I have now edited the jsfiddle to fix that problem. As I said, the translateY and margin-top on the `#aboutmecontainer` were throwing that off. Once you've fixed that you want to get rid of the inline negative margin-bottom on your `h5`.

Comment: Great - showing this link as I think it's almost the same solution but just with horizontally centred divs in left-hand column which is what I was going for :)

http://jsfiddle.net/ubjo1s3y/34/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)? It drastically simplifies this old height problem.

See this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/uy2pqbkL/

Everything else is the same except the new properties added to your .row class.

```
.row {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea @efru thank you! I'll definitely look into it, however, the dark green column box is still much longer than the element in column B. This is what I'm really confused about!